# When using [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:completion:] in a modal presentation, the animation block is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a `UIViewController` that is being presented via a modal segue in a storyboard (embedded in a `UINavigationController`). I'm trying to animate the keyboard appearance alongside the modal presentation (logic for this is beyond the scope of the question).

I'm using `[self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:completion:]` in `viewWillAppear:` to do this but I'm noticing that that the animation block is never being called. So a bit of logging has led me to see that the *only time* the animation block is called on a *newly created* modal view controller is during `viewDidLoad:`.

```
@implementation MyModalViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSLog(@"%s ANIMATION", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    } completion:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSLog(@"%s COMPLETION", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSLog(@"%s ANIMATION", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    } completion:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSLog(@"%s COMPLETION", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSLog(@"%s ANIMATION", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    } completion:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSLog(@"%s COMPLETION", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }];
}

@end
```

The output of a modal presentation of this controller is:

```
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] -[MyModalViewController viewDidLoad]
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] __36-[MyModalViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke ANIMATION
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] -[MyModalViewController viewWillAppear:]
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] __36-[MyModalViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_2 COMPLETION
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] __40-[MyModalViewController viewWillAppear:]_block_invoke_2 COMPLETION
```

but during dismissal the output is:

```
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] -[MyModalViewController viewWillDisappear:]
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] __43-[MyModalViewController viewWillDisappear:]_block_invoke ANIMATION
SampleAnimatedTransition[43690:1768171] __43-[MyModalViewController viewWillDisappear:]_block_invoke_2 COMPLETION
```

Notice how the animation block is not called in `viewWillAppear:`, and even more **annoyingly** the animation block from `viewDidLoad:` is called before `viewWillAppear:` is called at all.

Can anyone help me get the animation block is `viewWillAppear:` to be called?

Note that when I push another view controller onto the navigation controller and hit back, the animation block in `viewWillAppear:` *is* called.

I made a [Sample Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/565759/SampleAnimatedTransition_withpush.zip) if it helps.

### Update

This has been filed as [rdar://20171073](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5788623576236032)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're presenting a `UINavigationController`.  You can animate with that presentation by subclassing `UINavigationController` and overriding `-viewWillAppear:`.  However, at this point the navigation controller has not yet added its root view controller to the view hierarchy so any animations you set up will not work.

```
@implementation MyNavigationController
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^ (id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        NSAssert([self.viewControllers[0] superview] != nil, @""); // Fails
    } completion:nil];
}
@end
```

As it turns out, you can force UINavigationController to set up its view hierarchy by using `layoutIfNecessary`:

```
@implemenation MyNavigationController
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
@end
```

That also takes care of calling `-viewWillAppear:` on the root view controller at a point that allows you to animate with the modal presentation.

With this hack I'm able to animate along side the modal presentation.  It's ugly and I wouldn't use it, but it would at least allow you to test whether your approach at keyboard animation has any merit.

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, you may have more luck creating a custom modal presentation with `UIPresentationController`.

Comment: I'm going to create a Radar from this, definitely feels like a bug. When I present the modal directly, as you say, the `viewWillAppear:` animation block does get called, but it seems that `[self transitionCoordinator]` is not set in `viewDidLoad` in this instance. Completely different behaviour when embedded in a `UINavigationController` to without.

Comment: I had a similar problem with there being no animation when navigation back to a nested nav controller that had not previously appeared (via replaced in the stack or state restored). I had to put layoutIfNeeded in viewDidLoad rather than viewWillAppear in the nav controller subclass.